# How can I create a bar chart with kibana, using the percentage bar mode, with multiple filters on the x axis, shown as a percentage of the total?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I have created a bar chart in Kibana using the percentage bar mode, with two filters on the x axis. I simply want to show the distribution of the filters as a percentage of the total results from the search query. The problem is that all of the filters are showing as 100%, when this is not correct. So the visualisation is not actually showing the amount of results in the filter as a percentage of the total results. My visualisation options are shown in the images below:

[image: Data Tab]

And the Options tab:

[image: Options tab]

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but in case somebody is looking for a similar answer:

You need to use a bucket type "Split Series" instead of "X-axis".